# ojdbc14.jar not found while trying to run irca.bat

Tags: java, soap, soa

I have just dived into web services and trying to configure oracle soa suite 10g on window vista. I am stuck with running the irca.bat file with the following error:

```
cannot find library -jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar
Please verify that Oracle_Home is set correctly
```

I have used the SET command to set the Java_Home and the Oracle_Home and I can verify that they have been set still using the SET command. Am not sure what is wrong here. Need some help.

```
C:>SET ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN
C:>SET JAVA_HOME = C:\jdeveloper\jdevstudio10131\jdk
C:>SET ORACLE_SID = XE
```

Any comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That JAR is not in the CLASSPATH.  I would look in the script to see how it sets CLASSPATH.

Should ORACLE_HOME point to /bin?  I would have guessed that ORACLE_HOME should be either c:/oracleexe or c:/oracleexe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0.

I don't think JAVA_HOME looks right, either.  JDeveloper is not Java; are you using its JDK?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I got it sorted. The Oracle_Home should have been pointing to the SERVER. I was setting those variables at the c prompt. They disappear after sometime not sure why but I had to set them from the directory I was going to run the irca.bat file. Thanks for your post anyway. JDeveloper is the folder name that contains the extracted JDeveloper resources which includes the JDK.